# Which Java versions introduced which language features?

Tags: java

Is there any comprehensive resource on the versions that the different language features were introduced in for Java? For example where I can type or search for 'static initialization blocks', and it can tell me that this feature is available in Java since version xx.

Comment: Static initializer blocks were in the initial release

Comment: What is wrong with looking at wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: @pimaster: Thx. My googling was based on specific features like 'static initializer blocks java version', which doesn't generate hits. I can see now that some of the features that were there since day one are not listed in these version histories, but if you don't know, you can't be too sure. In any case, a more technical and detailed list won't hurt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below highlights a (non-comprehensive) list of changes between Java versions. Please add *major* changes to the language and platform.

[Java 1.0 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20080205101616/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/1996-01/sunflash.960123.10561.xml)

- Introductory version.

[Java 1.1 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20080210044125/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/1997-02/sunflash.970219.0001.xml)

- Nested classes
- Object serialization
- JavaBeans API
- JDBC
- Serialization & RMI
- Unicode 2.0 support

[Java 1.2 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816170028/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/1998-12/sunflash.981208.9.xml)

- `strictfp`
- Java Security Model
- JIT Compilation
- Swing
- Collections Framework

[Java 1.3 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20070817053430/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/2000-05/sunflash.20000508.3.xml)

- HotSpot VM
- JNDI

[Java 1.4 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20070815095726/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/2002-02/sunflash.20020206.5.xml)

- assert statement
- java.util.logging

[Java 5 Press Release](http://web.archive.org/web/20080207083457/http://www.sun.com/smi/Press/sunflash/2004-09/sunflash.20040930.1.xml)

- Primitive autoboxing
- Generic types
- enum
- Annotations
- Enhanced for loop
- Static imports
- Formatted input and output
- varargs

[Java 6 Features and Enhancements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/features-141434.html)

- New collection interfaces

[JDK 7 Features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/)

- try-with-resources
- Multiple exception-type catch
- diamond "operator"
- switch on strings
- Binary literals
- Underscores in integral literals
- Fork-Join Framework

[JDK 8 Features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features)

- Lambda expressions
- default & static methods on interfaces
- Stream API
- java.time API
- Nashorn JavaScript engine

Also, to have a more detailed analysis of Java language changes with each version, one can go through [Java_Version_History Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

Answer (score 3):

This [Link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-features-and-history/)
will summerize the main features added to specific version with each version name and it's relase date.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: That link only covers features up to Java 8.